# Tab complete on a custom list for a bash script

Tags: bash, autocomplete, scripting

I'm working on a script for fun to learn a bit more about how bash works and I can't seem to find a way to get this to work. Say I have a script that does something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Pick an animal!
Cats
Dogs
Birds
Snakes"
read ANIMAL
echo $ANIMAL
```

Now say I want to have it autocomplete so when you type `S<TAB>` it completes to `Snakes` during the `read`. I basically want to make a simple menu that you can tab complete each option. Anyone know a way?

Comment: I've never seen this. What doc have you read that says it has such feature?

Answer (score 0):

If you use bash, `read` have an option, `-e`, that allow autocompletion of user entry :

```
-e     If the standard input is coming from a terminal, readline 
       (see READLINE above) is used to obtain the line.  Readline  uses  
       the current (or default, if line editing was not previously active) 
       editing settings.
```

Unfortunately, I don't know how to set properly `READLINE` to customize it to propose your 4 possible animals... As it is write in `-e` option description, you have to read `READLINE` part within `man bash`, 
and more particularly `Programmable Completion` part with `complete` bash builtin. Or wait for a more skilled answer !

Comment: Okay cool that gives me a start! I'll start looking from there